# Action Script 3 On Click

Tags: actionscript-3

Before i start i want to let you know today is my first day with AS3.
I wanted to know how to do an onclick function in AS3.
For example i have button 1 ( as Instance name) 
and when clicked i want it to hide and show another box. this is what i found online but how can i make it on click.

```
this.button1.alpha = 100;
```

Thanks so much.

Comment: Note that in AS3 alpha values range from 0 to 1, not 0 to 100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want

`button1.addEventListener(EventType, callback);`

You replace `EventType` with a mouse event (such as `MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN`) and `callback` is a function that you define, which is called whenever the event occurs.

See the following example, taken [from this page on the FlashEnabled Blog](http://www.flashenabledblog.com/2007/06/12/as3-mouse-events-and-mouse-related-user-actions/):

```
// attach the event listener to this object, if you want a global event outside
// the current class attach to stage.addEventListener([event],[callback])

this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onMouseClickEvent);
// then make the callback
public function onMouseClickEvent(event:Event) {
  trace(event);
  if(event.buttonDown)
    // if primary button down, left mouse button
    trace(”left button was down”);
  else
    trace(”left button was not down”);
  }

}
```

The above code sample attaches a click event handler to `this` (whatever context this code is executed in - it could be global, or inside a class). Inside your event handler, you'd want to use the `Tween` class ([as explained on Kirupa.com](http://www.kirupa.com/developer/actionscript/tween.htm)) to animate the box out and the other box in.

Since you mentioned that it's your first day, note that `trace()` writes to the console.

Comment: i copied everything and changed this to button1 and it threw an error: The public attribute can only be used in a package on the event mouse down.

Comment: I didn't notice the public. If you are adding code directly into a frame on the timeline, you should be able to delete the word `public`.